# Posting To FB Page As Page

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK and trying to post to my page using the page name itself rather than my personal profile name.

I have generated a short-lived access token and then generated a page access token with the required permissions.

However I keep getting this error :
`Graph returned an error: (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \ either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \ and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \ requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \ sufficient administrative permission`

Would appreciate any help given because I cannot figure out what I have done wrong here.

Here is my code :

```
<?php

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
$userToken = 'xxx';
$pageAccessToken = 'xxxx';
$pageID = 'xxxxxx'; 
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
 'app_id' => 'xx',
 'app_secret' => 'xx',
 'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);
///Post property to Facebook
$linkData = [
 'link' => 'www.mydomain.uk',
 'message' => 'Test Post'
];

try {
 $response = $fb->post('/'.$pageID.'/feed', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
 echo 'Graph returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
 exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
 echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: '.$e->getMessage();
 exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
?>
```

Comment: Debug your page access token using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/, and verify that it actually contains the permissions you think it should. If it does, then the other possible reason is that the user that generated the page token, does not have the ability to post as the page.

Comment: Ok now I'm confused.. I requested all teh required permissions yet debugging the token only returned these scopes :
pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement, pages_read_user_content

Comment: Did you actually get _asked_ for the in the login dialog? Suggest you go remove the app from your user profile (https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications), and then try logging in again.

Comment: Just checked my permissions on the page and I have full control.
This person has full control
This person can manage everything you can, including the ability to give access to others, remove anyone from the Page (including you) or delete the Page.

Comment: Ok so deleted the app from personal and just checked the user token and all required permissions are now showing when debugged the token. Will try again and update here in a minute

Comment: Still same error. The scopes now showing are : pages_show_list, page_events, pages_read_engagement, pages_read_user_content, pages_manage_posts, pages_manage_engagement and they are the same for both the page token and user token

Comment: And your user has "sufficient administrative permission" on that page? Needs to be able to perform the CREATE_CONTENT, MANAGE, or MODERATE task on the page in question.

Comment: Yep , Content
Create, manage or delete posts, stories and more as the Page.
Messages
Send and respond to messages as the Page.
Community activity
Review and respond to comments, remove unwanted comments and report activity.

Comment: Try and make the request using Graph API Explorer, using the same page access token you are currently using in your code, and see what happens there.

Comment: do you know the url structure ? Ive tried PAGEID?message=Test Post&client_id=APPID&client_secret=APPSECRET&access_token=PAGE-ACCESS-TOKEN but got this : OAuth Exception A page access token is required to request this resource

Comment: Graph API Explorer has an explicit input field for the token. And you should add your parameters also via the UI, not hack them into the URL.

Comment: still same response

Comment: Sorry, not sure what is actually wrong then. Can only suggest that you double-check all values involved.

Comment: Just to double check I'm doing it correctly ... Im using the graph explorer tool to generate the user token ( which gives me a login popup ), then I'm exchanging that token using this https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=APP-ID&client_secret=APP-SECRET&fb_exchange_token=USER-TOKEN   This then returns a json result with a page access token.. is that correct ?

Comment: No, this is for exchanging the short-lived user access token, for a long-lived one. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens#pagetokens - but you don't need to go trough that trouble, you can switch to a page access token direct in GAE.

Comment: Dammit .. yep when changed dropdown to page access I copied the access token from input field above and it worked perfectly. Thank you for all your help :)